# creating an excel file in memory using java and pass as bytes for downloading

Tags: java, excel, jxl, in-memory

I have created a excel file using **jxl** library. The code is working fine but the only problem is that each time for building an excel file from the dynamic values coming from a service, the excel content is overwriting onto a **test.xls** like as shown below. Is there any way to build an excel in memory and pass the byte for downloading it instead of creating an external file ("**test.xls**")

```
File file = new File("test.xls");
WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file);
:
:
:
:

InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);

if (in == null) {
    out.close();
}
else 
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int len;

    while ((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }

    out.flush();
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

Can anyone please help me on this

Comment: hello, what's the ```out``` in your codes? thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` in combination with the [`Workbook.createWorkbook(OutputStream os)`](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/current/docs/jxl/Workbook.html#createWorkbook(java.io.OutputStream)) method to create the workbook in memory, and dump the created byte array to whatever output stream you want.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(baos);

// ...

workbook.close();
out.write(baos.toByteArray());
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Alternatively, you could do it on the fly, without using the intermediate byte array:

```
WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(out);

// ...

workbook.close();
out.flush();
out.close();
```

This method may be preferable as JXL is keeping the workbook in memory anyway, and only flushes it to he output stream when the workbook is closed.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this with Apache POI? thanks

Comment: The order of closing the workbook and the outputstream is very important here, it breaks in the latest versions of a lot of browsers if you close the outputstream before the workbook

Comment: hello, what's the out in your codes? thanks

Answer (score 16):

Here is example to create excel using POI and converting it to bytes.

```
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet 1");

    Row row = sheet.createRow(1);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
    cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        workbook.write(bos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } finally {
        try {
            bos.close();
            workbook.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
    byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
```